# Meta Head title on Drupal front page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

For some reason I didn't change the front page URL on the home page of one my drupal sites and it's a bit late to change it now (timings mainly).

Does anyone know how to change the head meta title on the front page in Drupal 7? This is driving me mad as I work in Drupal most days. Must be simple and I'm completely missing it!

Usually this would be the Page-title | Sitename if I could edit a page but not changing the default front page url in the configuration settings means its not directly editable by clicking on an edit button. At the moment it says Welcome to SiteName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grab this [Page Title](http://drupal.org/project/page_title), should solve all your problem as it separate "content title" from "Meta page title"

Comment: Thanks - I had seen this. I'll give it a go and see if it solves the problem.

Is there no other way to do it without using a module?

Comment: if you're at ease creating your own module, you could play with this code : [article](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/35951)